# Instagram redirect_url stripping query strings

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, instagram

So I'm working on developing a Instagram Basic Display call and for some reason it's stripping out a query string.

**Here is all the information**:
Where the /auth/authenticate/ button lived: `***/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=instagram_auth`

`$auth_url .= '/?client_id=' . $this->instagram->get_client_id() . '&redirect_uri=' . $this->instagram->get_redirect_uri() . '&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code';`

The auth window pops up with the following code and I can then authenticate:

https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=28822****&redirect_uri=****/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=instagram_auth&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code

Here is the problem:

When I click "Accept", Instagram redirects to:

`/wp-admin/options-general.php?code=AQBWjP-foZA7tkhUCTZygn5CBNbiJJxmY364eLPm0bD9NpetQbzUqJSw4LiueRDg_jiDzW8l_8js2JHFAZcPom8zFR-86x_*-X11H1-kTPCPrQ#_`

It strips out the `?page=instagram_auth` parameters which is needed inside my code.. My valid OAuth Redirect URI is: `***/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=instagram_auth`.

Does anyone know why the parameter gets stripped out?

Comment: When you introduce one URL _into another_ as a parameter, then you need to properly URL encode the value.

Comment: @CBroe, what's the best approach for this?

Comment: Just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php on the values you are inserting into that auth URL. Or use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php to begin with.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Tripp? I'm having a similar problem. urlencoding the URL doesn't seem to work, I just get told it's invalid by the API.

Comment: encoding the URL does not work. It yields the same result, i.e. redirects to `/wp-admin/options-general.php`

Answer (score 1):

There is a `state` parameter that can be added to the OAuth Authorize request which will be passed through when it redirects to your redirect URI.

```
An optional value indicating a server-specific state. For example, you can use this to protect against CSRF issues. We will include this parameter and value when redirecting the user back to you.
```

(From the Facebook Instagram API docs)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize